# How to show byte[] image in database with Fresco?

Tags: android, arrays, image, fresco

I am doing a camera project.The camera returns a byte array data.I saved it into a database.Now I want to use Fresco to show the byte[] image.How?

Comment: You should use : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: My project used Fresco.

Comment: see: https://medium.com/myntra-engineering/my-experience-using-fresco-b45cc36ac878

Comment: I defined a ContentProvider to access my database.The ContentProvider can provide a uri like "content://authority/tableName/primaryKey".But i can not find the way to support custom uri handlers in Fresco.It only supports LocalContactUri and LocalCameraUri.